Horror movie/TV-show about a man getting killed by puppets
When I was younger (around 9 years ago) I saw a clip from a movie or TV show. There was a guy taking a walk at night. I think he was in a park. I believe he had dark hair. He saw a puppet show and walked towards it. He watched the show for a little bit, and then I think the puppets killed him. It was either the puppets that killed him, or the man playing with the puppets. I think the man was killed with a knife.
Does anyone know where this is from? The scene was live action. I believe it was made in the U.S. and everything was in English. I think one of the puppets was a clown. The movie came out in the 90s, was in color, definitely American, and contained the same costume designs as Earnest Scared Stupid.

Hi! Welcome to Movies & TV. Hope we can help you! Is there any chance you remember more about the show/movie? e.g. Other scenes, other characters, what the characters looked like, etc? Non-plot-related info would be hugely helpful, too! e.g. What counts as "when you were younger" - 10 years ago, five years ago, last week? When do you think it came out ('80s, '90s, etc.)? Do you remember what language it was in and/or what country you think it might have been made in? You can add any info you remember by clicking the "edit" button beneath your post. Thanks!

Could be one of the puppet master movies. Or one of the demonic toys movies. Both series' also had a crossover with one another

The answer to this is Killer Clowns from Outer Space.  The scene you are describing happens when one of the clowns puts on a puppet show. I can add the answer when this is reopened. I also put in an edit to make your question more clear.

To El Bromista. Thank you, I think this was the right movie.

If the answer was correct, you should accept it and close this question.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

The answer is Killer Clowns from Outer Space.  In the scene you describe, the little clown puts on a puppet show. You can see the clip you remembered here: puppet show. The Chiodo Brothers did the Special Effects for this 1988 film.  They also happened to do the special effects in Earnest Scared Stupid.
